# html dom select object.value inconsistent

Tags: html, dom, select, duplicates

Consider following:

```
var ele = document.getElementById('someId');
alert(ele.value);
```

and ele is a select list.

usually the ele.value is the option value.  But sometimes it is the displayed text value.  Why is that?

This is from the same machine, same browser, same code.

Comment: Are you sure it's not something else? Pretty sure `ele.value` should be returning the value of the option, not the text. Can you post more information?

Comment: I finally figured it out.  It turns out the rendering engine can render different types of dom elements with the same ID.  Therefore ele might be textbox sometimes and textbox.value would have been the text inside it.  Sorry for the confusion, I plan to answer this question and vote my question down.

Comment: It turns out, I can't vote my own post down.  I am very sorry to have wasted your time.

Answer (score 0):

I want to apologize to the community for posting this question.  It turns out the rendering engine was not always rendering select tag and it can render a textbox using the same id.  Therefore my issue results from ele being textbox sometimes and select sometimes.